# How to schedule to send email in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC technology. Sending a mail is working fine in my project without any errors when we perform manually which means on click of a action, but I want make it happen everyday at scheduled time.

Please, can anyone help me? I don't know How to schedule it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Quartz.net for that look here : http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Quartz.NET.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/